# FreeTDS - Linux server problems - both server and SQL admins say it's properly configured

Tags: php, linux, sql-server-2008, freetds

First time user of FreeTDS. It is a "shared hosting" but we are the re-sellers and put in a ticket for them to install and configure it.

Situation:
We run a Linux setup ( we'll call them A ) and need to connect to a MSSQL database on a remote server managed by another company. We run a Red Hat variant I'm certain, and they have a Windows Server setup - We'll call them B.
So our Admins (A) assure us that they have properly installed and configured FreeTDS. Our Windows guys (B) have assured us they have opened up a port, allowed our IP address and setup remote access and given proper authorization to our account.

Yet, I still get an cannot connect to the database error using mssql_connect. I've gone back and forth with both sides on this and they both, while not blaming me, assure me of proper configuration on their end. I know I'm using the right user name and password, the right port number and proper IP address to the remote server. On top of this, I can telnet in and use fsockopen() to connect to the remote server. So the port is open and the IP unblocked, but I still get the error.

Am I doing something wrong? I'm terribly new to this (windows specifically), but when both 2nd and 3rd parties (As it were) say they are both doing things right, and my side of the deal is as simple as using mssql_connect() with the proper credentials, it makes it difficult. Top it off, the client is pissed that this isn't done yet, and the only explanation I have (due to the other parties having emailed the client saying their end is ok) is to plead that I'm new to this.

The actual error is:

> Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:1433 in /path/to/file/file.php on line 18
>   Error connecting to the database

I can't glean any other information - at least by any method I'm aware of.

I should not have taken this job, but is there any advice to be had - things to ask, ways to troubleshoot?  I'm at a dead end and any I'll be forever grateful for any help.

Comment: Check `dmesg(8)` and `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for SELinux AVC denied messages -- perhaps your SELinux policy needs to be extended.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a programming question, and therefore is off-topic here. It's a server configuration/ISP issue. It probably is more suited to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com), but definitely doesn't fit here. You might want to take a minute to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to familiarize yourself with what questions are (and aren't) appropriate to ask here. Thanks. :)